# Installing raspberrypi-kernel-headers: Unable to locate package raspberrypi-kernel-headers

Tags: raspberry-pi-desktop

I am Trying to install `raspberrypi-kernel-headers` using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install raspberrypi-kernel-headers
```

This is done on the **Ubuntu MATE 22.04.2.**

But, an error message pop up in the terminal telling:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package raspberrypi-kernel-headers
```

I tried to reinstall both the raspberrypi bootlodaer and kernels but no thing new, still having the same error message.

Looking forward to get an answer from you all.

Thanks in advance.